# Releasing ObjectContext while using StructureMap

Tags: entity-framework-4, dependency-injection, structuremap, objectcontext

I've been using StructureMap to inject ObjectContext (entities) into my repositories along with lazy-loaded POCO classes. This is my Structuremap registration.

```
 For<WebEntities>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle()).Use(()=>new WebEntities());
```

I have defined Partial classes against my POCO classes to retrieve info that is not defined in my EDMX schema. e.g. Community.FloorPlanImages would be a getter which filters only the floor plan images from all available Images. Worked pretty well until I started to optimize my queries. Using EFProf, I found out that none of my connections were being closed. I could not use an 'using' statement since I'm injecting the ObjectContext itself into my repository. So, I added the following in my Application_EndRequest().

```
ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
```

This works too as long as I don't access anything on my Partial POCOs. I think StructureMap is closing the connection before we get to the Partial. I'm presented with the following error.

The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Any ideas to get around this?

**UPDATE - Here's the stack trace**

> ObjectDisposedException: The
>   ObjectContext instance has been
>   disposed and can no longer be used for
>   operations that require a connection.]
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
>   +8550458    System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +46
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption
>   mergeOption) +31
>
>   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1
>   collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
>   +243    System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption
>   mergeOption) +25
>   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
>   +37    System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
>   +8032198    System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty(TItem
>   propertyValue, String
>   relationshipName, String
>   targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull,
>   Object wrapperObject) +85
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.<>c_*DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy
>   proxy, TItem item) +101
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Community_39641A615E1AD4E19D637735C7A1EBEE61BF70BF579CDD4EBB0267E6636BEC62.get_Videos()
>   +55    Rdx.Web.UI.AppCode.Controllers.CDController.GetCDModel(SearchParams
>   searchParams, Int32 page, Boolean
>   isSorting) in
>   D:\Solutions\RDX\Rdx.Mvc\src\app\Rdx.Web.UI\AppCode\Controllers\CDController.cs:365
>   Rdx.Web.UI.AppCode.Controllers.CDController.Show(Int32
>   cid, Int32 bid) in
>   D:\Solutions\RDX\Rdx.Mvc\src\app\Rdx.Web.UI\AppCode\Controllers\CDController.cs:70
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase
>   , Object[] ) +145
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +208
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass17.b_*14()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass17.b_*14()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass17.b_*14()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +343    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +116    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +97
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClassb.b_*5()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b_*0()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +62    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b__0(Action
>   f) +7
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8841105    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +184

**UPDATE 2: My Application_EndRequest is getting hit twice. What might cause that to happen? **

**STACK on first hit.**

> Nhs.Web.UI.DLL!Nhs.Web.UI.Global.Application_EndRequest(object sender = {ASP.global_asax}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 58 C#
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x95 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = true) + 0x4c bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x13e bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) + 0xad bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr = {System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6}) + 0x1a2 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 0x7d bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.IntPtr ecb, int iWRType) + 0xfd bytes
>       [Appdomain Transition]
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

**STACK on second hit**

> Nhs.Web.UI.DLL!Nhs.Web.UI.Global.Application_EndRequest(object sender = {ASP.global_asax}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 58 C#
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x95 bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step = {System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep}, ref bool completedSynchronously = true) + 0x4c bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x13e bytes
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsWaitCallback(object error) + 0x1e bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) + 0x2d bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 0x5a bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 0x147 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x2d bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Appdomain Transition]
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: Have you checked the stacktrace to see what triggers the use of the context when it fails? It seems either like the call is made after the request ends somehow, or that you are disposing the context before the request has ended. Look for stray usings/Dispose on the context and post your stacktrace.

Comment: I've posted the dump above PHeiberg. The page worked every time and then boom, it fails. Once it fails, it doesn't come back up. Driving me nuts now :(

Comment: Are you using AsyncController or some other asyncronous method that would cause the controller to switch threads?

Comment: No AsyncController as such. I do use AJAX to do GETs/POSTs.

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
For(typeof(WebEntities)).LifecycleIs(InstanceScope.Hybrid);
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
}
```

StructureMap will store the context every time that you do the access

```
var db = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<WebEntities>();
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm still getting the same result. It fails on extended properties of partial class. e.g. public ICollection<Image> Images
        {
            get
            {
                return (from i in this.AllImages
                        where i.VideoId == null
                        select i).ToList();
            }
        }

Comment: That's the same registration that the OP posted, but without generics. Why would that help?

Comment: @Praveen, I'll do the tests here... @PHeiberg, I'm just 'trying' to help, homeboy. :)

Comment: Funny thing is, it works as long as I don't navigate away to a different page. I've the scope set to HttpContext, so you'd think that it would spawn a new instance on the next request. For some reason, it still hangs on to the previous request.